# Double routes node.js

Tags: node.js, express, routes

When I add routes like this:

```
expressApp.use('/api/v1',require('./api')(expressApp, router));
```

I will be able to access:

`/api/v1/login` and `/login` anyone know what can be problem, I should be able to access just one route `/api/v1/login` ?

`.api` file:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(expressApp, router) {

    router = require('./account/router.js')(expressApp,router);
    router = require('./games/router.js')(expressApp,router);
    return router;
};
```

Comment: question isn't clear. also, if you could post some more code, that would be helpful. it might be useful to see what code you have in ./api or what other routes you have (where is your /login route defined?) etc. etc.....

Comment: I updated. It just load routes...

Comment: I still don't see a route anywhere for "/api/v1/login" or for "/login"

Comment: right now the only path that would watch your routing setup is "/api/v1" unless there is something in "./account/router.js" that matches "login"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.